# What does this statement means: "all = Promise.all.bind (Promise)"?

Tags: javascript, binding, promise

I know that `bind` will bind methods this to the object being passed. But, what I am not understanding here is that, why are we passing the class name to the bind?

One answer I got from an expert was, "this is to make the function 'independent'" which again, I didn't understand. I might be completely stupid to not understand and go completely mad over one statement, but, could anybody please explain this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a "class name," it's an object. (Specifically, a function; functions are objects in JavaScript. Even more specifically, a *constructor* function.)

`Promise.all(...)` looks up the `all` property on the `Promise` object and calls `all` with `this` set to `Promise`. So to do that with just `all(...)`, we need to bind the function so that `this` is always `Promise` even when we call it a different way. That's what `all = Promise.all.bind(Promise)` does.

If we just did `all = Promise.all`, then when we called `all(...)`, `this` during the call would not refer to `Promise` (it would be the global object in loose mode or `undefined` in strict mode). `all` [relies on](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-promise.all) `this` referring to a constructor function for promises (`Promise`, for instance).

> I know that `bind` will bind methods this to the object being passed

Let's put that a different way: `a = b.bind(c)` returns a new function (`a`) that, when called, will call `b` ensuring that `this` is set to `c` during the call. The result is called a *bound function*, because its `this` value is bound to it.

See also:

- [*How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)
- [*How does the “this” keyword work?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: *(Gah! If that last paragraph seems to have `a` and `b` mixed up, hit refresh.)*

Comment: Ok, I think i got it now! So... If we are "extracting" a function from its parent, we should make sure we bind its `this` to a proper object, so that we will not get any unexpected results. In this case, we are assigning `all` functions `this` to its actual parent, so that it will become autonomous.